# Error when adding a warning before deleting a django model record

Tags: django, loops, bootstrap-modal

I am looking to popup a model warning about the deletion of a model record, however when looping into a table, all links lead to delete the very first record in the table, what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:
#models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    office = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teamname

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['teamname']

class Contact(models.Model):
        teamname = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=CASCADE)
        firstname = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=20)
        lastname = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=20)
        position = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=(
            ('Option1','Option1'),
            ('Option2','Option2'),
        ))
        cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
        birthday = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str('%s, %s' % (self.lastname, self.firstname))
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['id','position','lastname','firstname']
```

html/bootstrap code:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive  nowrap w-100">
        <thead>
            <div style="text-align: center;" class="card-body">
                <h4>Contact list</h4>
            </div>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;">First name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Last Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Position</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Cellphone</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Email</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Birthday</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Edit</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for j in obj2 %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{j.firstname}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{j.lastname}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{j.position}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{j.cellphone}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="mailto:{{j.email}}">{{j.email}}</a></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{j.birthday}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="/clients/edit/contact/{{j.id}}" class="text-success"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil font-size-18"></i></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <i style="color: red; font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteRecord" class="bx bx-trash"></i>
                </td>
                <div class="modal fade" id="deleteRecord" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">¿Está seguro que desea proceder?</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p style="text-align: justify;">Data of contact {{j.nombre}} will not be recovered in the future.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Proceed</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**The problem is, when trying to delete any record in the table using the modal as a warning, the code triggers the details of the very first record and it works the deletion, but always the very first record, please help!**

Answer (score 0):

adrian please make sure your are using bootstrap5 because as i can in your modal code u are using bootstrap5 modal

for bootstarp4

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for bootstarp version 5 use this

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but there is no change, I am using bootstrap 5.1, however I think my problem is related to my model or view.

Comment: @Adrian add your views.py so i can have a look

Answer (score 0):

I found another post and this is solved by adding the id for the modal trigger and the target modal:

```
<td style="text-align: center;"><i style="color: red;cursor: pointer;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteRecord**{{i.id}}**" class="bx bx-trash"></i></td>

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteRecord**{{i.id}}**" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">...
```